# Array post through ajax is null in c# method

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, ajax

I am getting an array through a loop and passing it through an ajax call to my c# method but for some reason I am only getting null values in my parameter but count of the array comes through. Im not sure what I am doing wrong. For example the array before passing it through the ajax would have a count of 3, each key populated with the needed info, but as I pass it through the ajax call and debug on VS, the parameter for my list is null but has a count of 3?

```
let test = $('.divtest').map(function (index, element) {

    return {
        key1: $(element).closest('.testdiv')[0].id,
        key2: $(element).attr('id'),
        key3: $(element).attr('style')
    }
}).get();
```

Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: { test: test},
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/controller/testhere",
    success: function (result) {
      alert('done');
    }
});
```

C# Method

```
 public JsonResult testhere(List<string> test)
    {
       //stuff
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: try with `url: "/controller/testhere?text="+JSON.stringify(test)`

Comment: Huh, can I ask why try that method? @Vadim

Answer (score 0):

your action is a list of string but ajax data is not. try this data

```
let test = [ "key1", "key2", "key3"];
.....
.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: { test: test},
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/controller/testhere",
    success: function (result) {
      alert('done');
    }
});
```

or you will have to change the action

Create view model

```
public class TestViewModel
{
public string Key1 {get; set;}
public string Key2 {get; set;}
public string Key3 {get; set;}
}
```

action

```
public JsonResult testhere(TestViewModel test)
```

Comment: If I change my test variable to that then I'm not capturing the values I need? Would it then not be better to change my action from a list then to something that could accept what I'm needing?

Comment: @Jack, ok I updated my answer, try again

Comment: I did make the changes to my action and am still getting null for value passed in

Comment: I would be nice if you post your javascript object in json format.